How to select a specific bean per custom scope instance out of multiple candidates in Spring / Spring Boot?
I'm working on a multi-tenant Spring Boot web app. There is a twist: the count of tenants is low (up to 10), and tenants require to have customized business logic plugged into common API code.
Custom business logic is extracted in beans with very well defined interfaces.
I have a custom Spring scope TenantScope that stores beans in a thread-local map. A servlet filter sets the current map after interrogation of a header in an HTTP request. In essence, the custom scope behavior is very close to the RequestScope.
Let's suppose I have a component interface and two beans implementing the interface:
interface IService {
  String compute();
}

@Component
@TenantScope
class TenantAService implements IService {
  @Override
  public String compute() {
    return "Tenant A";
  }
}

@Component
@TenantScope
class TenantBService implements IService {
  @Override
  public String compute() {
    return "Tenant B";
  }
}

Both beans should be enabled in run-time, i.e., @ConditionalOn is not an option.
My goal is to configure Spring to create exactly one bean implementing IService per scope instance, i.e., TenantAService for a tenant A scope, and TenantBService for a tenant B scope.
The next step is to inject tenant-specific bean into singleton beans via proxy to switch between beans in run-time.
@Component
class CommonService {
  @Autowired
  private IService service;

  public String doCompute() {
    return this.service.compute(); // returns "Tenant A" or "Tenant B" depending on the current header value
  }
}

Is there a way to configure Spring to limit bean resolution to just one bean based on the current tenant scope?
I have a simple solution which I don't like.
I can configure CommonService to have a field List<IService> services to get all beans, then to select one bean by interrogating annotations on beans' classes.
It works, but it does not look nice and does not feel like an idiomatic Spring solution.

Have you considered not autowiring the IService instances?  It seems like you already have pretty much all the framework in place with your servlet filter, etc, to put the wanted object in your TenantScope, or even in one of the standard scopes, such that your components can get it from there.

Alternatively, have you considered not trying to serve different tenants out of the same application?  I anticipate that your design could be much simplified by assigning a different application instance (in the same application server) for each tenant.  Then it would just be a matter of configuration which IService is used in which application instance.

That’s absolutely true. I could enable tenant specific beans with a simple ConditionalOn annotation at start-time. Alas, it’s a mandatory requirement to have a single instance deployment serving multiple tenants to reduce cost of infrastructure.

Is there any sort of user role / entitlement that you could use to retrieve the corresponding service? i.e. if userA has entitlement A, compute using serviceA

You could use the composite pattern:
@Primary
@Service
public class CompositeService implements IService {
  @Autowired
  private final Set<IService> allTenantServices = null; // not null in runtime
  public void compute() {
    for(var svc : allTenatServices) {
      if (svc.isResponsibleByRequest()) {
        return svc.compute();
      }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Unknown tenant!");
  }
}

